# Suggestion Command Using Discord Buttons Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord

So I am trying to make a suggestion command using discord buttons in Discord.JS. When I run the command the embed and the buttons send but whenever I click one of the buttons whether it be **Upvote**, **Maybe**, or **Downvote** it edits the embed, but it never updates the number. I've tried `upvote_number ++` and `upvote_number + 1` but it doesn't work. It would be awesome if somebody could help me with this. Thank you.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const disbut = require('discord-buttons');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord-buttons");
const { Color, Prefix } = require("../../config.js");
  const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

  const disbutpages = require("discord-embeds-pages-buttons")
  const db = require('quick.db');


module.exports = {
  name: "suggest",
  aliases: [],
  description: "Suggestion Command",
  usage: "^suggest <suggestion>",
  run: async(client, message, args) => {

          const SayMessage = message.content.slice(8).trim();
    
    let upvote_number = 0
    let downvote_number = 0
    let maybe_number = 0
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Suggestion from: " + message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    .setDescription(SayMessage)
    .addField(`Votes`, `Upvote: **${upvote_number}**
    Downvote: **${downvote_number}**`) 
    
    
    let upvotebutton = new MessageButton()
    .setLabel(`Upvote`)
    .setID(`upvote`)
    .setEmoji(`⬆️`)
    .setStyle("green")
        
    let maybebutton = new MessageButton()
    .setLabel(`Maybe`)
    .setID(`maybe`)
    .setEmoji(``)
    .setStyle("blurple")
    
    let downvotebutton = new MessageButton()
    .setLabel(`Downvote`)
    .setID(`downvote`)
    .setEmoji(`⬇️`)
    .setStyle("red")
              
        
    let row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(upvotebutton, maybebutton, downvotebutton)
    

    const MESSAGE = await message.channel.send(embed, { components: [row] })

    const filter = ( button ) => button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id
    const collector = MESSAGE.createButtonCollector(filter, { time : 120000 });

    collector.on('collect', async (b) => {

      
        if(b.id == "upvote") {
          
await upvote_number + 1
          
           await MESSAGE.edit(embed, { components: [row] });
            await b.reply.defer()

        }
      
        if(b.id == "downvote") {
downvote_number + 1
            MESSAGE.edit(embed, { components: [row] });
            await b.reply.defer()

        }

        if(b.id == "maybe") {
            maybe_number + 1
            MESSAGE.edit(embed, { components: [row] });
            await b.reply.defer()

        }

    })

    collector.on('end', (b) => {
    })
    
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use the `+=` operator for your question. By the way, because of how button collectors work, the suggestions will be timing out after some time, which may cause you some issues in the future, so you may want to switch to the event. My only other concerns are that you are using `d.js 12` and `discord-buttons` which are both deprecated. As d.js 12 is losing support soon because of discord's api updates, I'd highly recommend switching to v13, as it has built in buttons, along with many other new features such as menus and slash commands.

```js
let upvote_number = 0
let downvote_number = 0
let maybe_number = 0

/* ... */

collector.on('collect', async b => {
    if(b.id == "upvote") {
        upvote_number += 1
        updateEmbed()
        await MESSAGE.edit(embed, { components: [row] })
        await b.reply.defer()

    } else if (b.id == "downvote") {
        downvote_number += 1
        updateEmbed()
        await MESSAGE.edit(embed, { components: [row] })
        await b.reply.defer()

    } else if (b.id == "maybe") {
        maybe_number += 1
        updateEmbed()
        await MESSAGE.edit(embed, { components: [row] })
        await b.reply.defer()

    }
});

updateEmbed(){
    embed.fields.find(i=>i.name==='Votes').value = `Upvote: **${upvote_number}**
    Downvote: **${downvote_number}**`
}
```

```markdown
tldr: Use += to set vars dynamically as well as update the embed object, and update to `discord.js@latest`
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, and I will make sure to update to Discord.JS V13, but it still isn't updating the number in the embed.

Comment: Hey, so I realized that I totally forgot to update the embed object, I edited my original post with the edits, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :D